# What is the purpose of NGINX and Gunicorn running in parallel?

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

A lot of Django app deployments over Amazon's EC2 use HTTP servers NGINX and Gunicorn.

I was wondering what they actually do and why both are used in parallel. What is the purpose of running them both in parallel?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13004484/deploying-django-with-gunicorn-and-nginx/13004973#13004973) which goes into a bit more detail than Timmy's answer.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

They aren't used in parallel. NGINX is a *[reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy)*. It's first in line. It accepts incoming connections and decides where they should go next. It also (usually) serves static media such as CSS, JS and images. It can also do other things such as encryption via SSL, caching etc.

Gunicorn is the next layer and is an *[application server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_server)*. NGINX sees that the incoming connection is for `www.domain.com` and knows (via configuration files) that it should pass that connection onto Gunicorn. Gunicorn is a [WSGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface) server which is basically a:

> simple and universal interface between web servers and web applications or frameworks

Gunicorn's job is to manage and run the Django instance(s) (similar to using `django-admin runserver` during development)

The contrast to this setup is to use Apache with the `mod_wsgi` module. In this situation, the application server is actually a part of Apache, running as a module.

Comment: @Timmy O'Mahony, What is the difference between wsgi file(coming when creating django project) and gunicorn

Comment: [This answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/220046/why-is-setting-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-a-good-idea) goes deeper into the details and benefits of nginx.

Answer (score 5):

*Nginx and Gunicorn are not used in parrallel.*

- Gunicorn, is a Web Server Gateway Interface (WSGI) server
  implementation that is commonly used to run Python web applications.
- NGINX is a free, open-source, high-performance HTTP server and reverse proxy, as well as an IMAP/POP3 proxy server.
- Nginx responsible for serving static content, gzip compression, ssl,
  proxy_buffers and other HTTP stuff.While gunicorn is a Python HTTP server that interfaces with both nginx and your actual python web-app code to serve dynamic content.

*The following diagrams shows how nginx and Gunicorn interact.*

[image: Nginx and Gunicorn][image: Overall idea of nginx and Gunicorn]